# how skip file in golangci-lint?

Tags: go, golint

I try go1.16

```
import "embed"
```

I get

```
> golangci-lint run ./...
> Can't run linter goanalysis_metalinter: bodyclose: failed prerequisites ... could not import embed
```

how skip file/package in golangci-lint?

Answer (score 9):

## Using a config file

You can customize the behavior with a config file. Docs are here https://golangci-lint.run/usage/configuration/. Make a `.golangci.yml` file that looks like this:

```yaml
run:
  skip-files:
    - main.go
```

## //nolint

You can add `//nolint` to the top of the file.

```golang
//nolint
package foo
```

See https://golangci-lint.run/usage/false-positives/

Comment: I think the problem may be related to these issues:
- [1466](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/1466)
- [913](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/913)

Comment: Ah, I see. Yea, I just ran my solution with a pkg does not exist, and it does not ignore it properly.